# How many people must be present at a party to guarantee that at least three of their birthdays are in the same month?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations

I keep getting 36 as an answer since if 36 people were present at a party, 36/12 (for the months in a given year) = 3. But this is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "worst case" would be two born in each month, hence $24$.  One more than that guarantees that some month (at least) must have (at least)  three birthdays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the Pigeonhole principle which says that if you have $m$ cages and you want to put $n>m$ pigeons in  those cages, then at least one of the cages must contain more than one pigeon. Let me give you an example. If you have $3$ cages, then at least how many pigeons should you have such that if you put them in those $3$ cages then at least $2$ pigeons must be in the same cage$?$ it can be easily answered, and the answer is $4$. Because if you try to put exactly one pigeon in those cages then after putting three pigeons in three cages one pigeon is left, and you have to put that in one of the cages which already contain one pigeon.

Similar is the case here. You have $12$ months, so if there are $24$ people in the party then it is possible that every two them has birthday in the same month. But if you take $25$ people then by Pigeonhole principle birthday of $3$ of them must be in the same month.

Answer (score 1):

If you had $24$ people you could have every month with two people having their birthdays then

But if you had $25$ then at least one month must have at least three people having their birthdays then, since the average number of birthdays per month would be $\frac{25}{12}>2$